# Pandas Exponential Moving Average with 15% Cap from Point to Point

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, moving-average, exponential

I can use this code to calculate an exponential moving average in Pandas:

`df['ewm_40'] = df['response'].ewm(span=40, adjust=True).mean()`

When there are some volatile data points, there can be a sharp increase in the exponential moving average that is undesirable.

**How would I cap the exponential moving average so no point moves more than 15% from the prior point?** I want to balance stability while still reflecting new data.

Comment: Can you post input data and expected output to make your code reproducible? thanks

Comment: Does my method answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, I compute the exponential moving average and update the values in order if they are increasing/decreasing more than a certain percentage.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [101, 103, 170, 10, 113]})

df['ewm_40'] = df['test'].ewm(span=40, adjust=True).mean()
print(df.ewm_40)

mx = 0.15

def sharp_increase(df, mx):
    return any(abs(df.ewm_40 / df.ewm_40.shift() - 1) > mx + 0.00001)

while sharp_increase(df, mx):
    perc = df.ewm_40 / df.ewm_40.shift()
    tf = list(abs(perc - 1) > mx)
    index = tf.index(True)
    
    if perc[2] > 1 + mx:
        multiplier = 1 + mx
    else:
        multiplier = 1 - mx
    df.loc[index, 'ewm_40'] = df.loc[index - 1, 'ewm_40'] * multiplier
    print(df.ewm_40)
```

Prints:

```
0    101.000000
1    102.025000
2    125.825453
3     94.662094
4     98.705363
Name: ewm_40, dtype: float64
0    101.000000
1    102.025000
2    117.328750
3     94.662094
4     98.705363
Name: ewm_40, dtype: float64
0    101.000000
1    102.025000
2    117.328750
3     99.729437
4     98.705363
Name: ewm_40, dtype: float64
```